# Mercurial: rename using --include option

Tags: mercurial, cygwin

I am trying to move(via the rename tool) a group of source files but still keep them tracked. Mercurial's rename tool has the --include option for handling multiple names. When I a try to move the files, I get the current directory added to the final name.  When I remove the preceding "./" only the file name is referenced.

I am using the `-I` option to include a pattern of files. For reference:

https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#rename

I am using Mercurial on windows through Cygwin64.

This is the directory that I am in:

```
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Users/me/thisProject/apple
```

This is what I want.

```
$ hg rename -f -v -I '*.c' ./ banana
moving one.c to .banana\one.c
moving two.c to .banana\two.c
moving three.c to .banana\three.c
```

This is what I don't want.

```
$ hg rename -f -v -I '*.c' ./ ./banana
moving one.c to banana\apple\one.c
moving two.c to banana\apple\two.c
moving three.c to banana\apple\three.c
```

Why does adding a "./" to the destination add the current directory name as an extra folder in the output?

Comment: you asked to move `./`  under `banana`. Have you tried just `hg rename -f -v -I '*.c'  banana` ?

Comment: @matzeri `hg rename` requires a source and a destination, the `-I` option will eat up the first input, making the second the source and leaving the `rename` without a destination.

Comment: @matzeri Is what you were implying that I shouldn't use the `-I` option at all?